# Why c++ can't printf vector B[0]？

Tags: c++, linux, vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::vector<double> B;
    B[0]=0.5 * log(sqrt(2) + 1.0);
    printf("%f",B[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

It's a easy c++ code. But it can't printf correctly. It shows me**Segmentation fault**. Why?(**linux,C++11**)

Comment: You have no index 0. First reserve space for index 0

Comment: thank you for help.@acraig5075

Comment: `B[0]=0.5 * log(sqrt(2) + 1.0);` -- Change that to `B.at(0)=0.5 * log(sqrt(2) + 1.0);` and you will get an `std::out_of_range` exception thrown instead of a segmentation fault, basically explaining what the problem is.

Comment: Related, since your are using C++, you should use std streams like `cout` rather then `printf`. No need to try to get half pregnant. Go all the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared an empty vector. So you may not use the subscript operator, Insetad use the member function push_back.

For example

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::vector<double> B;
    B.push_back( 0.5 * log(sqrt(2) + 1.0) );
    printf("%f",B[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Another approach is initially to define the vector with one element like

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::vector<double> B( 1 );
    B[0]=0.5 * log(sqrt(2) + 1.0);
    printf("%f",B[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<double> B` creates an empty vector and `B[0]` tries to access the first element of it, which does not exists. **Segmentation fault** is usually for accessing memory not available for you. What you should do in this situation is `push_back` the value `'0.5 * log(sqrt(2) + 1.0)'` into `B`.